# How to create a new branch from existing application code in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

We've been working on a version of an application that was originally checked out from a Tortoise SVN trunk. Unfortunately though, instead of creating a new branch first from that trunk, then committing and updating our changes to that new branch, we've been passing the app back and forth between us and never created a branch for it. Now I would like to create a branch and put the updated application into it. Can I do that? Can you please tell me how?

I added an empty branch folder to the application in Tortoise SVN but I haven't found a way to add my existing code to it. Everything I've found in searching online has been about creating a branch from the trunk or working copy, and I don't think that option is possible now.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "passing the app back and forth".  Also, I don't think this should be tagged C#, asp.net, nor visual-studio-2013.

Comment: Agree. Are you saying you just kept changing the code you checked out, without ever committing or updating? So you still have a working copy based off the old code, and you have some new code you want to be in a branch instead, that is not currently in SVN at all?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I translated you correctly

> I have RX:RY range in trunk, which I want to see as special branch

then your modus operandi is just wrong. You have to:

- Create branch from trunk's Rev. X (`svn copy ^/trunk@X ^/branches/branchname`)
- Merge range X+1:Y from trunk to created branch (`svn merge ^/trunk -r X+1:Y .`, where . is WC of branch)

PS: I'm too lazy to show these operations for TSVN, they are obvious in "translation"